# Ensuring components are properly initialized

Tags: angular

I have started all guarding all components from initializing with

`<my-component*ngIf="someInput" [input]="someInput"><my-component>`

Is there a better way to ensure that the input exists before initializing the component?

Is there any performance reason to allow the component to initialize without the input and perfom the check within the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest consideration is the design choice and how these components interact. How does the child component relate to your parent? Will the parent toggle the input between true or false? ngIf destroys a component when false which can be good for performance if the component is heavy but not always necessary if lightweight.

The performance reason for rendering the component before the data is so that it initializes and displays on the screen faster. If the input is async and takes a while to load, then the component will not display at all on the page until the input is ready. Rather it might be a better user experience to render the child component first and displaying a loading symbol until the input arrives.